# DebugDiag PerfAnalysis always fails due to a System.Argument exception

Tags: debugdiag

I have tried collecting several dumps with DebugDiag for CPU usage, but each time that I try to analyze the dump, whether a mini dump on the server, or a full dump on my workstation, it results in a report like this:

[image: DebugDiag Exception]

There is nothing more lower down. DebugDiag always just seems to fail to read the dump file. Is there anything that can be done to rectify the situation, or should I proceed to look at other tools?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the exact same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately no. Tried a couple of different things but never got it to work. Figure I just have to take the plunge and learn how to use perfview...

Comment: I'm trying this with WinDbg, maybe you can give it a shot too: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/16/lab-19-debugging-a-high-cpu-hang-w3wp-process-using-windbg/

Comment: The same question has been asked in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/374d4e9e-4624-487f-8d8e-6e3c3e09e0c4/debugdiag-perfanalysis-fails-with-systemargumentexception and there it is suggested to open the dump with DebugDiag Update 2. I had the same problem and going back to that version PerfAnalysis succeeded. But I have no idea about how to fix this problem with Update 3